# Where is the ferris wheel in Sinuiju, North Korea?

Tags: sightseeing, locate-this, north-korea

The [North Korean](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/North_Korea) city of [Sinuiju](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Sinuiju) has a ferris wheel, visible from [Dandong](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dandong):

[image: Sinuiju ferris wheel]

What is its exact latitude/longitude?

I could not find it despite Google Maps being rather detailed in this area.
The object at [40.11079, 124.39409](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.11079,%20124.39409&hl=en&sll=40.11079,124.39409&sspn=0.014146,0.031629&t=h&z=16) can not be the ferris wheel as it lacks a central axis and does not have trees in front of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're only off by a couple hundred meters.

The problem is that the available satellite imagery is not very detailed, not sufficiently to make an object this small (when viewed from above) *clearly* visible. From above an object of this size is not quite as wide as a lorry, and perhaps as long. So, as we can see from the satellite image, which *does* capture some lorries, this will be difficult to spot.

(I think the problem you had is that the ferris wheel is actually much smaller than you originally thought. A close up picture from the ground is below and makes this clear.)

Let us review what we know:

[The image you posted is also on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Never_moving_North_Korean_ferris_wheel.jpg); from its description we find out that it was taken from the end of the Broken Bridge. And one of the derelict bridge supports is visible in the picture. So the ferris wheel is between the bridge supports and the building with the blue roof.

[Another picture](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/12943631) puts it in perspective, and gives us more detail to work with.

[image: 断桥-原本通向朝鲜的部分 by ypspace; CC BY-NC-ND]

Looking on the satellite image, down a line from where the bridge would have been, we spot the building with the blue roof to the right of the ferris wheel at [40°06'38.9"N 124°23'48.3"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B006'38.9%22N+124%C2%B023'48.3%22E/@40.1108056,124.39675,448m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0).

Secondly, we look at [this picture of the ferris wheel and nearby carousels from the ground](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/98548353), (not inlined due to copyright) and match them up with the satellite view.

This places the ferris wheel at almost exactly [40°06'42.0"N 124°23'45.4"E](https://www.google.com/maps/place/40%C2%B006'42.0%22N+124%C2%B023'45.4%22E/@40.1116667,124.3959444,224m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0). (While I don't think this is exactly centred on the ferris wheel, if you are standing at that spot you should be able to touch some part of it.)

Comment: I had also found [a picture from the opposite side of the building](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/112397782) which is behind the ferris wheel in [the second picture](https://ssl.panoramio.com/photo/98548353), but decided not to use it as it didn't appear to be necessary to confirm the location, _and_ that building is sufficiently visible in the satellite image to confirm this as the location without it.

Comment: The shadows of the ferris wheel's gondolas are now visible on Google Maps' satellite view.